# Finding the LastRow from Excel Attachment via Outlook VBA

Tags: vba, excel, outlook

I've been searching for an answer to this particular issue but I can't seem to find one. I am trying to combine multiple Excel-based lists that I receive as e-mail attachments. Just to give a little context, this macro has been working for almost two years without error but I recently switched it from a system running Excel 2007 & Outlook 2010 to a system running Excel 2007 & Outlook 2007.

The following line is giving me an `1004: Application-defined or object-defined error`:

`LR = xlAtt.ActiveSheet.Range("A" & xlAtt.ActiveSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row`

in context the code is:

```
Private Sub ProcessAttachments(olFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder)

Dim xlApp As Object, xlAtt As Object
Dim LR As Long

Dim olItem As Outlook.MailItem
Dim count As Integer

Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
xlApp.Visible = False

For count = olFolder.Items.Count To 1 Step -1
  Set olItem = olFolder.Items.Item(count)

  If olItem.Class = olMail And olItem.Attachments.Count > 0 Then
    'Omitted a few lines here that verify if the attachment is an Excel file
    'and then saves it to a folder
    Set xlAtt = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("pathToFile")
    xlAtt.Activate
    LR = xlAtt.ActiveSheet.Range("A" & xlAtt.ActiveSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

'More VBA after
```

The above is just a snippet of the code but hopefully gives enough context.

I have tried testing each individual piece of the line giving me an error and I've been able to narrow it down to the `.End(xlUp).Row` portion of the line.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: does it work if you use the `xlUp` enumeration `-4162`, It's perplexing to me why it stopped working, because you are still using XL2007 and binding it to XL in the code. If the enumeration doesn't work, did something change with the attachments that you are opening that may be returning a different `ActiveSheet` than you expect?

Comment: Scott, please place this in an answer so I can accept it. Using the enumeration worked! Thanks.

Comment: I suspect the previous version of Outlook had a reference to the Excel library but the new one doesn't.  Open the Outlook VB Editor, click `Tools` then `References`.  Near the top you should have "Microsoft Excel nn.0 Object Library" with a ticked box to its left.  The value of "nn.0" depends on the version.  If it is not at the top, scroll down to this libray and tick it.  All Excel constants will now be available.

Comment: @TonyDallimore the references were all properly ticked. I believe Outlook 2007 simply doesn't interpret the Excel constants properly on my system.

Comment: I find that very difficult to believe. The Excel library worked perfect with Outlook 2003.  I do not have a copy of Office 2007 to test but I do not believe an Excel/Outlook would not have been fixed by now.  You imply you are using Excel 2007 with Outlook 2010.  Have you loaded the correct Excel library with Outlook?

Comment: That's cool. Thanks for your input :) @TonyDallimore

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Outlook 2007 must not recognize the Excel Constants, whereas OL 2010 does.

Instead of writing `xlUp` write the enumeration for `xlUp` which is `-4162`.

So your code would look like this:

```
LR = xlAtt.ActiveSheet.Range("A" & xlAtt.ActiveSheet.Rows.Count).End(-4162).Row
```

To find any enumeration for any constant in Excel VBA, once inside the VBE, press `F2` to open the Object Browser and type the constant into the box next to the binoculars, then click the binocular. Click on the constant in the search results and the box at the bottom will show the enumeration.

Alternatively, you could set a constant variable to the enumeration and still use `xlUp` in your syntax by:

```
Constant xlUp = -4162
```